# How to frame odata PUT request using objectid of mongodb and o.js

Tags: javascript, mongodb, odata

I am trying to write a odata client for odata mongodb server using o.js.
Request http://localhost:27017/resumedata(5a9f72ebe0f23d8e609e4f63) is throwing "404 (Not Found)" error.
How object id of mongodb can be used in above request?

Comment: have you cheked that mongodb is running on port 27017?

Comment: @dynamo yes, mongodb is running on port 27017 and I am able to get data for http://localhost:27017/resumedata.